# Parse output from Django timesince to float days with javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I have the output of the tag filter `timesince` such as

```
{{ item.submit_date|timesince }}
1 day, 12 hours
```

How can I parse it to days in javascript, so it can return me an float in days, for example

```
var sktime = {{ item.submit_date|timesince }}
var result =  parseTimesince(sktime)
```

Then I want the function give me the result in days like

```
1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't. Output the date itself and use that in your JS.

Comment: I want to parse it to a float days for make calculations

Comment: Yes. Do that in JS, based on the date.

Comment: This is the question :/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `naturaltime` filter. It should do the job.

> For datetime values, returns a string representing how many seconds,
>   minutes or hours ago it was – falling back to the **timesince** format if
>   the value is more than a day old. In case the datetime value is in the
>   future the return value will automatically use an appropriate phrase.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: You could also make the calculation yourself in js
`1 day = 1440 minutes/day`

Comment: I only want to conver it to days. For example, timesince filter gives me: 1 day, 12 hours. I want to take this string to JS and then parse it like: 1.5